# Flutter Add to Favorite Function from JSON Data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I have a Json List which I am fetching in my app in ListView. at the top, in the App bar, I have an IconButton which navigates to favorited Page. I have a detailed page of my Json listview Data, in the detailed page, I have attached an IconButton, which toggles icon for making Favorite and unfavorite the list data.
updates_details.dart

```
class UpdateDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final String detail;
  UpdateDetails({this.detail});

  @override
  _UpdateDetailsState createState() => _UpdateDetailsState();
}

class _UpdateDetailsState extends State<UpdateDetails> {

  bool _isFavorited = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Updates',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        elevation: 0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35)
            )
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 5),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            icon: (_isFavorited ? Icon(Icons.favorite,size: 35,color: Colors.pink,) : Icon(Icons.favorite_border,size: 35,)),
            onPressed: _toggleFavorite,
          ),
        ],

      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child:
        Html(
          data: this.widget.detail,
          style: {
            "html": Style(
              fontSize: FontSize.xLarge,
            ),
            'Strong': Style(color: Colors.blue)
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _toggleFavorite() {
    setState(() {
      if (_isFavorited) {
        _isFavorited = false;
      } else {
        _isFavorited = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now when I click on IconButton, it is changing from favorite to unfavorite. Now, please provide me the solution to save these listview's details page as favorited or unfavorited with the help of shared_preferences and I can get all favorited Item in listview from my Favourite page.

here is my listItem Page.  recent_updates.dart

```
class RecentUpdates extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecentUpdatesState createState() => _RecentUpdatesState();
}

class _RecentUpdatesState extends State<RecentUpdates> {

  List<RecentUpdate> _updateList = List<RecentUpdate>();
  RecentUpdateService _recentUpdateService = RecentUpdateService();
  bool isLoading = true;

  _getRecentUpdates() async {
    var updates = await _recentUpdateService.getRecentUpdates();
    var result = json.decode(updates.body);
    result['data'].forEach((data) {
      var model = RecentUpdate();
      model.id = data["id"];
      model.title = data["title"];
      model.details = data["details"];
      model.image = data["file"];
      setState(() {
        _updateList.add(model);
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRecentUpdates();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35)
            )
        ),
        title: Text('Recent Updates',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,size: 35,color: Colors.pink,), onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>FavoritePage()));
          }),
          SizedBox(width: 10,)
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          strokeWidth: 10,
        ),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _updateList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          if(_updateList.length != 0){
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    FadeInImage(
                      placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/kids.png'),
                        height: 110,width: 100,
                        image: NetworkImage(_updateList[index].image, )),
                    SizedBox(width: 5,),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 280,
                            child: Text(_updateList[index].title,maxLines: 2,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                        FlatButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UpdateDetails(
                              detail: _updateList[index].details
                            )));
                            },
                            child: Text("Read Details",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white),))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Here are my model class
updates.dart

```
class RecentUpdate{
  int id;
  String image;
  String title;
  String details;
}
```

Please provide me suggestions and solutions. Thank you

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to store RecentUpdate object in json form in sharedPreferences

So first of all you have to make your model serializable:

```
class RecentUpdate {
  final int id;
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String details;
  RecentUpdate({
    required this.id,
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
    required this.details,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'image': image,
      'title': title,
      'details': details,
    };
  }

  factory RecentUpdate.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return RecentUpdate(
      id: map['id'],
      image: map['image'],
      title: map['title'],
      details: map['details'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory RecentUpdate.fromJson(String source) =>
      RecentUpdate.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

then you need three functions, I'll just write psudo code and debug it yourself

```
void save(RecentUpdate r) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List rups = [];
  if (prefs.getString("fave") != null)
    rups = json.decode(prefs.getString("fave"));
  rups.add(r.toMap()); 
  prefs.setString("fave", json.encode(rups));
}

void delete(RecentUpdate r)async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List rups = [];
  if (prefs.getString("fave") != null)
    rups = json.decode(prefs.getString("fave"));
  rups.remove(r);
  prefs.setString("fave", json.encode(rups));
}

Future<List<RecentUpdate> read() async{
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List rups json.decode(prefs.getString("fave"));
  return rups;
}
```

also this may help https://betterprogramming.pub/flutter-how-to-save-objects-in-sharedpreferences-b7880d0ee2e4

Comment: please tell me what is the source in factory RecentUpdate.fromJson(String source) =>
      RecentUpdate.fromMap(json.decode(source));

Comment: please provide me full example .

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the list page you should have a favorite icon for every item, Not in the app bar.

Comment: Actually that is a button to navigate Favourite page and  I want to make favourite from list details page